# Need help in splitting a string

Tags: java, string, split

I am trying to split a string

```
String strLine="sadf={asdf;=};asdfa ={sfasdf} as}; asdfa ={sfasdf};";
```

in a such that the output should be like this

```
   ={asdf;=};
   ={sfasdf} as};
   ={sfasdf};
```

I have try this code

```
String str1=strLine.substring((strLine.indexOf("=")),strLine.indexOf(";")+1);
        strLine=strLine.substring((strLine.indexOf(";")+1));
```

but I am not getting the result I want..

Comment: ...so the rule is to cut whenever you have a `=` that is not inside a `{`...`}` block, while ignoring unmatched closing `}`?

Comment: 'but i am arriving at the result which i want' - presumably this is a typo. What does your code actually output?

Comment: Or is it that lines are terminated by a right brace followed by a semicolon? The braces don't seem to be forming blocks, as they're not always in pairs.

Comment: Question is edited for earning a +2, but the last line says "I am arriving at the result I want.." Means he got the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the most elegant way to do this, but it does what you need:

```
    String[] st = strLine.split("};");
    for (String s : st) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf("=")) + "};");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int i1 = strLine.indexOf("=");
int i2 = strLine.indexOf("};", i1);
String s = strLine.substring(i1, i2 + 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to split the String. I would suggest you use Regular Expression for this purpose. Find the pattern in your search.

For just an idea try to search pattern starts with `=` and having `{`, `}` and semicolon in the end.

And find all the groups that matches the pattern.

Example:

```
Regular Expression = ".*(=\{.*\}.*;)*.*"
```

Comment: But what about the = and ;. It also should be included right according the output. I would also suggest regex if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String strLine="sadf={asdf;=};asdfa ={sfasdf} as}; asdfa ={sfasdf};";

        String[] s=strLine.split("};");
        String str1=s[0]+"};";
        String str2=s[1]+"};";
        String str3=s[2]+"};";
        System.out.println(str1+" "+str2+" "+str3);
```